How can I center-align icon + text using Divi + Divi Supreme
I hope someone can help me with this. Been struggling for a few days now. Last resort is to do this manually.
Screenshot below is how my site icons are now. I'm using Divi and this one is a Divi Supreme icon list module. I've tried all sorts of adjustments but I can't get the icon to center-align with the text below.
current look
Current CSS:
selector span.dsm_icon_list_icon {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
selector span.dsm_icon_list_wrapper {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
selector span.dsm_icon_list_text {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

Here's how the html code looks like now:
current html code
Hope someone can help me. Please! 
I've tried all sorts of adjustments on the CSS, trying all the solutions I found here & on other sites, but I can't seem to get it to look like how I need it.
I hope you can help me get the icon on top of the text be vertically centered.

Not even sure how the text can be under with just those css, so i assume there are something else to keep it that way. So my guess is just add left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%) to selector span.dsm_icon_list_icon can do the job
